# Display develops strange colour issue after system suspends [16.04]

Tags: 16.04, display, suspend, power-management

For the last couple of months my system produces a strange problem with its display:

[image: screenshot]

This will happen every time I close the lid or the system is left idle and suspends. The way I resolve the issue is a reboot and to just shut down whenever I'm planning on closing the lid.

Is there a way to fix this without the need to reinstall the OS? I don't have time to set everything up again at the moment but would obviously like the functionality back as this hasn't always happened.

**Any help is much appreciated!**

Comment: Thanks, for this @karel. It's a little difficult to put into words and search for.

Comment: I've asked a mod to un-delete your question. Just because it's a duplicate doesn't mean it should be deleted. Duplicates can serve as signposts to the master question.

Comment: Hi @AndroidDev, that makes sense. Especially with an issue that's a bit difficult to put into a single description. I always thought the preference was to try not to clog up the site with duplicates.

Comment: It depends on the quality of the duplicate. If someone asks a very unclear question with horrible grammar etc, we might not keep it around. But your question is clear and features a screenshot, so it is definitely worth keeping. As an added bonus, questions that are closed as dupes with no answers (such as is the case here) will automatically redirect to the master question if the link is clicked from a search engine like Google :)

Comment: Ah, I did not know about the redirect! I was always thinking of keeping the search engine returns clean for those looking for answers who maybe aren't members yet.  I'll remember this if it happens again.

Comment: Just for grins have a look at the ridiculous amount of dupes of your exact issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/linked/896221?lq=1